# How to animate the selection in LazyGrid with Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am doing the UI effect like this with Android Compose.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If9AY.gif)

I implemented with below code. But it's not a good way and it causes bug when drag the Grid.
Please give me some suggestions to implement it with diffrent ways.

```
fun GridView2() {
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var offsetX by remember {
        mutableStateOf((selectedIndex % 4) * 207f)
    }
    var offsetY by remember {
        mutableStateOf((selectedIndex / 4) * 150f)
    }

    val animatedOffset by animateOffsetAsState(
        targetValue = Offset(offsetX, offsetY), label = "",
    )

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(200.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            items(count = 20) { index ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(200.dp)
                        .height(150.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            selectedIndex = index
                            offsetX = (selectedIndex % 4) * 207f
                            offsetY = (selectedIndex / 4) * 150f
                        },
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(190.dp)
                            .height(140.dp)
                            .background(Color.Gray)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(207.dp)
                .height(150.dp)
                .offset(
                    x = Dp(animatedOffset.x),
                    y = Dp(animatedOffset.y)
                ),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(190.dp)
                    .height(140.dp)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Offset` of a selected item from `LazyGridState`. In `LazyGridState`, there is a list called `visibleItemsInfo` in the `layoutInfo` property.

```kotlin
val lazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()

// get visible items' info
// visibleItemsInfo has item's info as LazyGridItemInfo
lazyGridState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
```

You can use `index`, `offset` properties from `LazyGridItemInfo` to animate the offset.

```kotlin
val lazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()

var selectedItemOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }
val selectedItem by derivedStateOf {
    lazyGridState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        .find { it.index == selectedIndex }?.also { selectedItemOffset = it.offset.toOffset() }
}

val animatedOffset by animateOffsetAsState(targetValue = selectedItemOffset, label = "")
```

The values from `LazyGridItemInfo` are pixels that you need to convert them into dp.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Int.toDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@toDp.toDp() }

@Composable
fun Float.toDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@toDp.toDp() }
```

Comment: It works for me. Appreciate for ObscureCookie.
I used remeber like this. 
val selectedItem = remember {derivedStateOf {}}

Comment: @wang_0088 Oh I forgot to add remember block. It is needed when you use a compose state directly in a compose function. It's my bad.